# Dependent origin operating mind

Tags: mindfulness, mind

During  walking meditation it happens automatically,without any initiation.understanding of dependent  origin lead to fear of sansara. Is it the doer of the  mind cause upadana?

Answer (score 2):

> During walking meditation it happens automatically,without any initiation

There is an *intention (Cetana)* behind every movement in the walking meditation. If you look carefully it can be seen. There's e.g. an intention to lift the foot, move it, lower it, place it, etc. With practice one will begin to see intentions everywhere such as the intention to swallow, to blink, even behind a thought, there's an intention to think.

With consistent practice this part of reality will reveal itself.

Answer (score -1):

Buddha did not talk about a doer. What he said was "Thanha pccaya Upadana" (craving is the cause for clinging)

Comment: What is than a?

Comment: Thanha = craving

Comment: tanha = craving. this forum is english language or, for Pali, Roman script. Make an effort to not confuse others by practising metta for readers

Comment: Experience there is a mind that operating very  speed and not worth.what is that?

Comment: Are you familiar with the seventeen though moments?

Comment: No I am not. What is that speed mind is?

Comment: The mind occurs in both passive and active modes.https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/mendis/wheel322.html#causality